# Android - Get Variable in Catch Handle Exception

Tags: java, android, try-catch

I'm new programmer here and I made an app to calculate area, side length, and diagonal of a rectangle. However, I'm stuck if I input non numeric value and it made the app crashed. The input type for the text field is already set to numeric keyboard.

Here is the code,

```
public void onClick(View view) {

            double w;
            double h;
            String width = editWidth.getText().toString().trim();
            String height = editHeight.getText().toString().trim();
            String result;


                try {
                    int widthException = Integer.parseInt(width);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {result = "Numerical input is needed!!";
                }


                if (editWidth.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    w = 0;
                } else {
                    w = Double.parseDouble(width);
                }

                if (editHeight.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                    h = 0;
                } else {
                    h = Double.parseDouble(height);
                }

                double area = Math.round(((w * h) * 100.0)) / 100.0;
                double sideLength = Math.round(((2 * (w + h)) * 100.0)) / 100.0;
                double diagonal = Math.round(((Math.sqrt(w * w + h * h)) * 100.0)) / 100.0;
                result = "Area : " + area +
                        "\nSide Length : " + sideLength +
                        "\nDiagonal : " + diagonal;


                txtResult.setText(result);

        }
    });
```

If I input decimal separator in the text field and press the run button, the app will crash even I already wrote the try-catch block. Did I write the try-catch block correctly? If I did, why result variable in catch block can't be used for txtResult.setText()?

Here's the logcat:

```
06-21 21:05:49.903    8263-8263/comyukitothepriest.facebook.www.hitungluas E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: comyukitothepriest.facebook.www.hitungluas, PID: 8263
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.initialParse(StringToReal.java:163)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:263)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
        at comyukitothepriest.facebook.www.hitungluas.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4444)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18457)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5113)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 06-21 21:05:49.923    1753-2479/? I/octvm_klo﹕ [am_crash][1466517949]:[8263,0,comyukitothepriest.facebook.www.hitungluas,8961606,java.lang.NumberFormatException,Invalid double: "",StringToReal.java,63]
```

Comment: Post the logcat exception please

Comment: You guarded yourself against exception in parseInt, why didn't you do that in parseDouble?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add two more `try/catch` block when you use `Double.parseDouble(...)`

```
if (editWidth.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    w = 0;
} else {
    try {
         w = Double.parseDouble(width);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         // do something
    }
}

if (editHeight.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
    h = 0;
} else {
    try {
         h = Double.parseDouble(height);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
         // do something
    }
}
```